# How to find duplicate characters in a string and concat them to a new string

Tags: java, concatenation, nested-loops

- I take in a string `aabullc`
- returingStrin should be assigned `aall` after the loop since `a` and `l` are duplicates
- strings with more then 1 dupe like example: (3x `a`). `aaabullc` will never be passed in

  ```
  public static String rearrangeLetters(String S)
  {

  String returnString;

   for(int i = 0; i<S.length()-1; i++){
       for(int j = i+1; i<S.length()-1-i; j++){
           if(S.charAt(i) == (S.charAt(j))){
           String char1 = String.valueOf(S.charAt(i));
           returnString = returnString.concat(char1);
           }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(returnString);

      return returnString;
  }
  ```

**Code briefing:**

- nested for loop starts at first letter in string and compares to the second letter until it reachs the end.
- the inner loop length gets sorter depending on the outer loops.
- if character matches we add it to `returningString`

**Issue:**
does not like `String char`

Comment: `concat(...)` creates a new string.  You are throwing that new string away.   Should be `returnString = returnString.concat(S.charAt(i));`.  And there are better ways to write that.

Comment: `charAt(...)` returns a `char`.  That is a primitive type.  Use `==` to compare primitive types.

Comment: A `String` does not have a (public) `length` field.  But it does have a `length()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char` is a reserved keyword in JAVA. So it cannot be used as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

This Java program is used to find the duplicate characters in a string and prints all the duplicate characters when the loop terminates.

```
public class DuplicateString {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String str = "Hello World";
        String newString="";
        int cnt = 0;
        char[] inp = str.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("Duplicate Characters are:");
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < str.length(); j++) {
                if (inp[i] == inp[j]) {
                    newString+=inp[j];
                    cnt++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newString);
    }
}
```

Program Output:

```
Duplicate Characters are:
llo
```